# How to find lowest populated array [lowest filled in] from top to bottom [evenly distributed as much as possible]

Tags: vb.net, fill, flood-fill

This is very hard to explain so I put a picture to explain it, it's basically like a fill flood algorithm but for 2d multi-dimensional arrays. Start from top left and end at bottom right. Lowest empty value (not colored in the image) is outputted. To mess around with fills in debugging set bits in array FilledBits. for testing.

[image: example]

```
'Lowest populated array [lowest filled in].
Dim LowestFilledColumn As Integer = Integer.MaxValue
Dim LowestFilledRow As Integer = Integer.MaxValue

For Row = 0 To Uniques.Length - 1
    For Column = 0 To Uniques(Row).Length - 1
        If Row <= LowestFilledRow AndAlso Column <= LowestFilledColumn AndAlso FilledBits(Row)(Column) = 0 Then
            LowestFilledRow = Row
            LowestFilledColumn = Column
        End If
    Next
Next
```

also tried this

```
'Lowest populated array [lowest filled in].
Dim LowestFilledColumn As Integer = Integer.MaxValue
Dim LowestFilledRow As Integer = Integer.MaxValue

For Row = Uniques.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
    For Column = Uniques(Row).Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Row <= LowestFilledRow AndAlso Column <= LowestFilledColumn AndAlso FilledBits(Row)(Column) = 0 Then
            LowestFilledRow = Row
            LowestFilledColumn = Column
        End If
    Next
Next
```

also tried this which is very close to what I need but I cannot adjust it for my likings [Breadth-First Search]

```
Dim LowestRowBFS As Integer = Integer.MaxValue
Dim LowestColumnBFS As Integer = Integer.MaxValue
Dim foundLowestBFS As Boolean = False
Dim queue As Queue = New Queue()

queue.Enqueue("0,3")

While queue.Count() > 0

    Dim x As String = queue.Dequeue()
    Row = x.Split(",")(0)
    Column = x.Split(",")(1)

    If Row < 0 OrElse Column < 0 OrElse Row >= Uniques.Length OrElse Column >= Uniques(Row).Length OrElse FilledBits(Row)(Column) = 1 Then Continue While

    Console.WriteLine("output = " & Uniques(Row)(Column) & " row:[" & Row & "] column:[" & Column & "]")
    FilledBits(Row)(Column) = 1

    queue.Enqueue(Row & "," & (Column - 1)) 'go left
    queue.Enqueue(Row & "," & (Column + 1)) 'go right
    queue.Enqueue((Row - 1) & "," & Column) 'go up
    queue.Enqueue((Row + 1) & "," & Column) 'go down
End While

If foundLowestBFS AndAlso LowestRowBFS = Integer.MaxValue Then
    LowestRowBFS = Row
    LowestColumnBFS = Column
End If
```

Here is the demo test code

```
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 0, 1)
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 0, 2)
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 0, 4)
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 0, 3)
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 1, 1)
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 1, 2)
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 1, 3)
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 1, 4)
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 2, 3)
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 2, 2)
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 2, 1)
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 3, 8)
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 3, 2)
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 3, 1)
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 4, 2)
AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(Uniques, 5, 2)
```

```
Public Uniques()() As Byte
Public FilledBits()() As Byte


Public Sub AddUniqueValueNoFilledBits(ByRef Uniques()() As Byte, Row As Integer, Value As Byte)
    'Resize array if not existing.
    If Uniques Is Nothing Then
        ReDim Uniques(0)
        ReDim Preserve Uniques(Row)
        Uniques(Row) = New Byte() {}
    End If

    'Re-size array if needed.
    If Uniques.Length <= Row Then
        ReDim Preserve Uniques(Row)
        Uniques(Row) = New Byte() {}
    End If

    'Add new number to this row
    Dim TotalColumnsInRow As Integer = Uniques(Row).Length
    ReDim Preserve Uniques(Row)(TotalColumnsInRow)
    Uniques(Row)(TotalColumnsInRow) = Value

    'Resize array if not existing.
    If FilledBits Is Nothing Then
        ReDim FilledBits(0)
        ReDim Preserve FilledBits(Row)
        FilledBits(Row) = New Byte() {}
    End If

    'Re-size array if needed.
    If FilledBits.Length <= Row Then
        ReDim Preserve FilledBits(Row)
        FilledBits(Row) = New Byte() {}
    End If


    'Set Filled Bit Flag to 1
    TotalColumnsInRow = FilledBits(Row).Length
    ReDim Preserve FilledBits(Row)(TotalColumnsInRow)
    'FilledBits(Row)(TotalColumnsInRow) = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: What I need is something like a Breadth-First Search which I can adjust and start it at any offset to get the next value.

Comment: Can someone help me out on this one please